# Partially updating a model with BooleanFields with djangorestframework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model like this

```
class Status(models.Model):
   
   is_working = models.BooleanField(
        default=None,
        null=True
   )

   is_at_home = models.BooleanField(
        default=None,
        null=True
   )
```

with the corresponding serializer

```
class StatusSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Status
        fields = [
          "is_working",
          "is_at_home"
        ]
```

using the default ModelViewSet

```
class StatusViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    """
    serializer_class = StatusSerializer
    queryset = Status.objects.all()
```

Whenever I partially update a `Status`, by e.g calling the `put` method on the API, all other fields are reset to `False` instead of keeping their old value.

Say, I have a `Status` that looks like this:

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "is_working": null,
   "is_at_home": null,
}
```

If I call `put` using the following JSON:

```
{
   "is_working": true
}
```

my data now looks like this

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "is_working": true,
   "is_at_home": false <-- GOT UPDATED
}
```

I however, just want to update the `is_working` field, so that my desired result would be:

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "is_working": true,
   "is_at_home": null
}
```

This probably has to do with the fact that HTML forms don't supply a value for unchecked fields. I, however, don't use any HTML forms as I'm purely consuming the API through JSON requests.

Using the serializer as is, I'd need to perform an extra get request prior to updating the model, just to get the state of the fields I don't want to update.

Is there a way around that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, for partially updating you need to have a PATCH request and not PUT.

Since you are using ModelViewSet drf should automatically recognize that and set partial=True and update only the fields which were sent in the api payload.
[ModelViewSet doc- DRF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset)

Answer (score 0):

You can make your is_at_home field read only in serializer as PUT method is updating it. Try this in your serializer.Hope this will work for you.

```
class StatusSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    
        class Meta:
            model = Status
            fields = [
              "is_working",
              "is_at_home"
            ]
            extra_kwargs = {
                'id': {'read_only': True},
                'is_at_home': {'read_only': True},            
            }
```

Comment: Sure, but what if I want to update `is_at_home`? Is there no way to tell DRF to leave these fields alone?

Comment: then you can use PATCH instead of PUT method.